How to use a calender system to prevent participants using the same date & time arrangement?
I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible through REDCap (but I am also a newbie), but here is the pickle:
We are trying to implement a calendar system to block certain dates from being picked, if they are fully booked, or only some of the slots are available. So basically, I would like to disable potential participants from selecting the same dates.
I thought of making a table with all the options (we will update all potential testing dates every two months), then limiting that option from being picked by using @MAXCHOICE-SURVEY-COMPLETE.
But on a table every option could be picked (See the image:).
Of course it is possible to manually write down and use the same logic, I was just wondering if there is a more elegant way to do that (meaning easier, and simple looking).
Is there a way around it on REDCap? Thanks a lot for the help!
